# How to use proximity sensor in android with unity3d?

Tags: android, unity, platformer

I want to create a android game with unity3d using proximity sensor an I don't know how to access that sensor with java script

Answer (score 1):

There is the [GyroDroid](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/101279-GyroDroid-2.0-Access-each-and-every-sensor-on-Android-devices-RELASED) (at the time of writing, costs 35$), which enables access to "every single sensor of your Android".

However, I guess you can try to find how to access Android's sensors using mono, if that is the target platform for Unity's Android games, and apply that to your Unity project.